# Trace log Example does not work in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, trace, sharepoint-2010, logging, web-parts

The Sharepoint Trace Log Sample given at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979522.aspx & explained at /en-us/library/aa979595.aspx does not work in in Sharepoint 2010. Any ideas of how to Write to Trace Log from webpart( non-sandboxed)

Answer (score 2):

From [How to write to ULS Log in SharePoint 2010 from a .NET app?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/how-to-write-to-uls-log-in-sharepoint-2010-from-a-net-app)

> This has really improved in SP2010.
>   Now you can write to the ULS logs
>   easily even with SharePoint
>   Foundation. All you have to do is
>   this:

```
SPDiagnosticsService diagSvc = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
diagSvc.WriteTrace( 0, // custom trace id
new SPDiagnosticsCategory("My category", 
TraceSeverity.Monitorable, 
EventSeverity.Error), // create a category
TraceSeverity.Monitorable, // set the logging level of this record
"Writing to the ULS log:  {0}", // custom message
new object[] { "SharePoint rocks!"} // parameters to message );
```

> Works great, but not available in
>   sandboxed solutions...